# SOLR 9 - org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.XSLTResponseWriter'

Tags: solr

I am trying to setup SOLR 9 and keep getting the error : org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.XSLTResponseWriter'

I have been reading up the docs and found: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/solr-modules.html which suggests to use the flag:

```
-Dsolr.modules=scripting
```

I have tried running solr with the flag:

```
C:\> solr start -p 8988 -Dsolr.modules=scripting
```

but still keep getting the same error.

Is there anything else that I need to do to get it running?

Comment: Have you checked if the Solr log gives you any useful feedback when starting up about attempting to load the scripting modules?

Answer (score 4):

The namespace for XSLTResponseWriter has changed between Solr 8 and Solr 9.

Here is the configuration for Solr 9: (note the class attribute)

```
<queryResponseWriter name="xslt" class="solr.scripting.xslt.XSLTResponseWriter">
    <int name="xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds">5</int>
</queryResponseWriter>
```

Instead of Solr8's

```
<queryResponseWriter name="xslt" class="solr.XSLTResponseWriter">
    <int name="xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds">5</int>
</queryResponseWriter>
```

I found the information here:

https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/response-writers.html#xslt-response-writer